# Ansible loops and conditions with arrays

Tags: ansible, stdout

I want to be able to control the behaviour of a module by specifying a changed_when condition. This works fine when executing a simple task like the one in the docs:

```
- command: some command
  register: command_result
  changed_when: "command_result.rc != 2"
```

The problem comes when I start using loops. I can't figure out how to access stderr, stdout, rc results from the current iteration of a loop. For example:

```
- command: aptly mirror update some-mirror
  register: aptly_output
  changed_when: "?item?.stdout | search('Download queue: 0 items')"
```

All results go to `aptly_output.results`, but how do I access the result of the current iteration?

Answer (score 0):

In one of our roles we do this:

```
- name: themes | activate
  command: "wp-cli --allow-root --no-color --path='{{ item.0.path }}' theme activate {{ item.1.name }}"
  register: check_activate_theme
  changed_when: "'Success: Switched to' in check_activate_theme.stdout"
  with_subelements:
    - wordpress_installs
    - themes
  when: item.1.name and item.1.activate | default(false)
  tags:
    - wordpress-themes-activate-theme
```

I think this should also work for your use case.

Comment: Interesting, it works in 'changed_when:' but fails in 'when:' which I was using for debugging.

Comment: I was doing the same thing but it fails in 'when', then I tried the search filter, also fails. Shouldn't these conditions work the same in both places? Hmm probably when is executed 'before' the command and 'changed_when' after... makes sense.